# How to convert string text from notepad into array line by line?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner in programming. I am currently learning how to convert texts from notepad into array line by line. An instance of the text in notepad,

> I am a high school student
>   I love banana and chicken
>   I have 2 dogs and 3 cats

and so on..

In this case, the array[1] will be string 'I love banana and chicken'.
The lines in the notepad can be updated and I want the array to be dynamic/flexible. I have tried to use scanner to identify each of the lines and tried to transfer them to array. Please refer to my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("notepad.txt");     
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            i++;
        }

        String[] stringArray = new String[i];

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            stringArray[j] = line;
            j++;
        }

        System.out.println(stringArray[2]);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I am not sure why there is runtime-error and I tried another approach but still did not produce the result that I want.

Comment: please post your error message

Comment: You probably run into an infinite loop. Correct?

Comment: `array[1]` needs to be 2-dimensional to contain "I love banana and chicken". Otherwise this would be just the space behind "I", i.e. the second character.

Comment: @user8 Why? A space is a perfectly valid part of a string. I suspect the issue is here: `scanner.hasNextLine()` is used twice. It needs to be re-initialized to re-use it.

Comment: Actually, as Mureinik points out, `scanner.hasNextLine()` is an infinite loop since `nextLine` is never called.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider OP said "array[1] will be string 'I love banana and chicken'"

Comment: I fail to see why that requires a 2D array... These are `String` arrays, not `char`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Yes, I just flew over the question. And didn't see that he meant `stringArray` by `array`. But this doesn't change the fact that `stringArray[1]` is not `"I love banana and chicken"`. So OP should in best-case scenario edit his question in order to remove such ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by creating an `ArrayList` and then converting it to the String Array.

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("notepad.txt"));
    List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

    String input = null;
    while (in.hasNextLine() && null != (input = in.nextLine())) {
        outputList.add(input);
    }

    String[] outputArray = new String[outputList.size()];
    outputArray = outputList.toArray(outputArray);

    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the starter code. This really solved my problem. It seems that my problem lies in the lack of understanding between array and list. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first loop would be infinite because you check if the scanner has a next line, but never advance its position. Although using a `Scanner` is fine, it seems like a lot of work, and you could just let Java's nio package do the heavy lifting for you:

```
String[] lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("notepad.txt")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want array to be dynamic/flexible, I would suggest to use List in such case. One way of doing this -

```
List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("notepad.txt"));
```